# Proof of countable intersection of dense and open sets in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I wanted to see if my proof of the Baire Category Theorem in $\mathbb{R}$ is correct.

Let $\lbrace D_n \rbrace$ be a collection of dense, open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.
We want to show every open $W \subset \mathbb{R}$ intersects $\bigcap_{1}^{\infty}D_n$.

To that end, let $W$ be non-empty, open, and take $x_1$ and $\epsilon_1 > 0$ in $W \cap D_1$ s.t $B_{\epsilon_1}(x_1) \subset W \cap D_1$. We can do this because $W \cap D_1$ is also non-empty and open. This ball is open, and hence its intersection with $D_2$ is non-empty, open. So, we can choose $x_2$ and $\epsilon_2 < \frac{{\epsilon}_{1}}{2}$ such that $B_{\epsilon_2}(x_2) \subset B_{\epsilon_1}(x_1) \cap D_2$.

Similarly, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, choose $x_n$ and ${\epsilon}_n < \frac{{\epsilon}_{n-1}}{2}$ s.t $B_{\epsilon_n}(x_n) \subset B_{\epsilon_{n_1}}(x_{n-1}) \cap D_n$.

Then, $\lbrace x_n \rbrace$ is Cauchy, hence convergent, say to $x$. Then, $x$ will be in $\bigcap_{1}^{\infty}D_n \cap W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I don't know if I should let this be an answer or a comment since it's a "long comment" so I'll just make this an answer)

The proof seems mostly valid as-is (and this version can be generalised to complete normed $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces), however the "interesting" part of the proof (at least to me) *is* showing that $(x_n)_n$ is a Cauchy/convergent sequence, so detailing that part at least a little might be worth it. You chose to divide by $2$ the $\varepsilon_n$ after each step so I suspect you already know why and how it works but still.

Moreover, to make sure the limit $x$ is in every $D_n$, you might want to enforce/emphasize having the closed ball - let's denote it with $B'_{\varepsilon_n}(x_n)$, I don't know the usual English notation for a closed ball - be included in $B_{\varepsilon_{n-1}}(x_{n-1}) \cap D_n$ during the construction and not just the open ball.
Much like for showing $(x_n)_n$ was convergent, detailing that part of the argument should tell you why the closed ball is pretty much needed here.

I don't have anything to say for the rest though, it's clear, concise and shows what needed to be showed!

EDIT: Wanted to go back on this. I did overcomplicate things, as I thought, by requiring summation when it's not necessary. I feel very silly right now...
Your proof can be generalized to all complete metric spaces by using the fact that the decreasing intersection of countably many closed subsets such that the sequence of their diameters converges to $0$ is of the form $\{y\}$ (and there is a version of it in $\mathbb{R}$ that you could use without all the machinery of complete metric spaces).
So the choice of the speed of convergence towards $0$ of $\varepsilon_n$ wouldn't matter with that argument, however it still does without that argument, and what I said about closed vs open balls is still relevant in both cases.

Comment: Do we require the balls to be closed even when we are requiring that the successive $\epsilon$'s be strictly smaller than half the previous one? The balls get smaller and smaller, and hence the sequence becomes Cauchy. Also, how would the proof change if instead of taking $\epsilon_n < \frac{\epsilon_{n-1}}{2}$, we simply let $\epsilon_n < \frac{\epsilon_1}{n}$?

Comment: The balls being closed is needed to say that, since all the $x_k$, $k \geq n$ are in the closed ball for $x_n$, $x$ is also in that closed ball, and *thus* in $D_n$. With just the open ball, you cannot say for certain that $x$ is in $D_n$, just that it's in $\bar{D_n}$. As for the choice of rays, as it stands you're only sure that the differences $|x_{n+1} - x_n|$ are small, but not that the sequence is Cauchy. For example, and it's probably a big hint but whatever, the sequence defined by "$H_n := \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$" respects $H_{n+1} - H_n = \frac{1}{n+1} \to 0$ yet it diverges.

Comment: The closed ball condition, i.e, given $x \in X, \exists \epsilon$ s.t $\overline{B_{\epsilon}(x)} \subset X$, isnt it called the local compactness condition? Shouldn't the lemma hold in complete metric spaces? Am I missing something?

Comment: If by lemma you mean the Baire lemma/theorem, then yes, it holds in all complete metric spaces, however this exact version of the proof relies on being able to *sum* the differences $x_{n+1} - x_n$: the series converges absolutely thanks to the construction (for example by diving the $\varepsilon_n$ by $2$ to have a geometric series with the norms of the differences), and so converges by completeness, but the series of the differences converging is equivalent to the sequence $(x_n)_n$ converging. Since you need (I think) to sum, you sadly at least want a group structure to work with.

Comment: Just to be clear, that doesn't mean there isn't a way to "salvage" this proof for more general complete metric spaces. *I* might not know but maybe someone else knows a way.